# Migration of big database from SQL Server 2008R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

Although there are several topics on this subject, but my question is bit different.
I have large number of records on SQL Server 2008R2, and i have purchased SQL Server 2008 enterprise to manage my data in a better form, now i am worried about database as it is online and being used by hundred of customers right now, i can shut down database for some time, but the thing is which mode i should use to migrate the data, there are several modes like

1. Using MDF
2. Using Script file with objects and data
3. Using bak file

I am confused which mode will be suitable as the data is in large number, data is important and i also dont want to loose foreign keys relationships.

FYI, Current database is 2008ExpressR2 where as it is going on 2008 Enterprise which is not R2.

Comment: You cannot use neither backup/restore nor detach/attach if you're going from a newer version (2008 R2) "back" to an older version (2008). You'll need to script out all the tables and data and move `.sql` scripts across to the older database server

Comment: will it maintain the foreign key relationships?